# $\forall xA\Rightarrow A[t/x]$ and rule of left universal quantification in sequent calculus

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

Consider the rule of left universal quantification in the sequent calculus:
$$\dfrac{\Gamma,A[t/x]\vdash \Delta}{\Gamma,\forall xA\vdash\Delta}.$$
This can be used to give the following proof:
$$\dfrac{A[t/x]\vdash A[t/x]}{\dfrac{\forall x A\vdash A[t/x]}{\vdash (\forall x)A\Rightarrow A[t/x]}}$$
What is the relation between $\vdash(\forall x)A\Rightarrow A[t/x]$ and left universal quantification rule? Obviously one is a sequent and the other a deductive rule. They aren't saying the same thing, right?

Comment: The relation is the same between the [ND rule](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) called $(\forall \text E)$: $\dfrac {\forall x A}{A[t/x]}$ and the valid formula: $\forall x A \to A[t/x]$ that we can prove using the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously one is a sequent and the other a deductive rule.

Yes, indeed, and that *is* the distinction.

The sequent, $~\vdash (\forall x~A)\to A[t\backslash x]~$, is the claim that the implication is *provable* to be a tautology.

The Left Universal Rule is *one* among the rules of inference used to do so.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{A[t/x]\vdash A[t/x]\qquad\;}{\small\textsf{Id}}}{\forall x A\vdash A[t/x]\qquad}{\small{\forall}\textsf{L}}}{\qquad\quad\,\vdash(\forall x)A\to A[t/x]}{\small{\to}\textsf{R}}$$